# JBOSS AS 7 JMS configuration

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, activemq-classic

I am new to JMS and I face the following problem:

I have a active MQ broker on a remote machine .

I have message sender and consumers for it in a JBOSS AS 7 server.
How do i configure the resource adapter in jboss as 7 to send and recieve messages from remote active mq?

what the different configuration that is done in ra.xml and iron-jacamar.xml?
and what is the configuration to be done under resource adapter subsystem?

where to configure the remote server url to establish the connection?

i have tried the following source :

http://blog.coffeebeans.at/?p=230

But i get the error :

BAS014809: A node is already registered at ‘(deployment => activemq-rar-5.5.1.rar)

Answer (score 1):

ra.xml is the generic file for spec compliant usage.
ironjacamar.xml is the descriptor for IronJacamar, JBoss's JCA implementation.

It sounds like you have both the .rar file and the .rar folder deployed.  You should only have one.

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding , could you explain more about the different configuration that is done in ra.xml and iron-jacamar.xml?

Comment: Also what configuration is required under resource adapter subsystem?

Comment: Based on what you've described, it's not clear how you've setup.  You should only need to drop the files in that this blog post describes.  I would recommend checking out the iron jacamar site to find all the different configuration options available.